# Does a Contacts Nickname transmit to anyone else; iMessage or email?

Tags: ios, email, contacts, siri

iOS 9.0.2

So I asked Siri to call me Sugar Daddy... Hilarious, right?

Well I was using the e-mail app this morning, and when looking at a few e-mails I sent last night, I noticed that my name was put as "Sugar Daddy" in those e-mails as well. I then realized that Siri had put "Sugar Daddy" as my nickname (while retaining my real first and last names) in Contacts and that the e-mail app displays the nicknames of contacts.

Is there any chance the people I sent e-mails to also saw my name as "Sugar Daddy" in the sender field? At least one of them uses iOS himself. Please tell me this is not possible... I realize this is unlikely, but I just want to make sure.

Btw, I'm honestly not trolling, this seriously happened to me.

Comment: Every time I see my nickname as "the boss" in a list of emails sent out to associates I freak out a little bit inside. Are you sure, I mean absolutely sure, that my Siri given nickname does not transmit to anyone else? Why does it even pop up there in the context of the email sent to field, which implies that it would be seen that way by anyone who has the same sent to or received by information. This is the only place on the Internet with this question is being brought up, I find that hard to believe but this is all I can find.

Comment: @Todd I agree that this is super creepy, and quite of a bad design my Apple. When you ask Siri to call you something, that should **stay** with Siri, and not be input into the contact card. This is because Siri is something lots of people have fun with (there is even an iPhone ad where a guy asks Siri to call him "Rockstar"), while contact cards are something serious that you would send to colleagues, etc. in professional contexts. So this is an extremely bad design by Apple. However, to answer your question, I think the current answer is correct, though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Todd If you're worried about this, I recommend you remove the funny nickname from your contact; simply for the peace of mind, if nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to laugh - but there's a serious question here, for sure.

Does a nickname in your Contacts show to anyone else?

Empirically, I would say **no** - neither a nickname you give yourself nor any other contact will be transmitted.
My partner & I have each other listed in Contacts with the nickname "ICE" [In Case of Emergency] yet it doesn't show up in any messages or emails we send to each other.
Similarly, my own nickname of Tetsujin is not seen by others in any communication I send.

I'm pretty sure you're safe asking Siri to call you Sugar Daddy… unless she does it in public, or if you ever intend to pass your vCard to someone, because it certainly **will** be in the exported card  ;)

Comment: Another thing to be careful with, is that I sometimes send my contact card to others. In that case, it would not be good to have "Sugar Daddy" in the nickname field. lol.

Comment: Yup - that would be one to avoid - because that **does** export as part of your vCard. I'll add that to the answer, in fact...

Comment: Alright, great.

Comment: I think it might be worth updating the Question title to be more generic, so Googlers will have a better chance of finding it if they have similar concerns

Comment: Good idea, got any suggestions for a new title?

Comment: I had a go - feel free to tweak or change, if you're not happy with it.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Cool. Welcome to Ask Different, btw - nice first question :)

Comment: Thanks. :) I just switched to OS X from Ubuntu this week, so I'll probably be asking some questions in the future, mainly about AppleScript.

Comment: However, something that should definitely be mentioned: if you share your contact card with someone, your nickname will go with it!

Comment: @timothymh - yes, as I added to the answer already

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the nickname does indeed transmit. I just received an email and chose “reply all.” The sender’s nickname for herself and for the other contacts in the CC box included her nicknames for me, my husband, and her husband. Even her unicorn emoijo for her husband appeared.

Comment: What you describe is what happens if those characters are in the name fields proper. You would have to see a screenshot of the sender iOS contact card to confirm of course, but this doesn’t add up with empirical testing.