# How to set Title in Contacts but not display it?

Tags: macos, mac, contacts, contacts.app

Is there a way to set the 'Title' field in Contacts, but to not display it?  i.e., in Mail I want to see "John Doe", but have the contact card display "Captain John Doe".

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it as a Nickname instead. Then it would only be seen by you.

Don't hand the contact card to anyone, though, as it would be in that.

See [Does a Contacts Nickname transmit to anyone else; iMessage or email?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212497/does-a-contacts-nickname-transmit-to-anyone-else-imessage-or-email/212501#212501) for a cautionary tale ;-)

A friend of mine has been "Young Master Johnson" <sup>[fake name]</sup> for 15 years without anyone else knowing.

Comment: That's not quite what I want.  I want to be able to see the Title, but only inside the Contacts.app.

Comment: Anything you add to Contacts will be seen system-wide by any app that uses it, including iDevices.